# Move auto-generated Custom XAML Paths to Top left?

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, path

I'm not sure the best way to do this... I've created some 'Icons' using tools suck as Inkscape and then saved them as XAML files. For an example find the code at the end of the post.

The problem is, if I place these items in my application they don't appear at the top left of the canvas, and I can't seem to get Inkscape to save it there (when it does eventually save correctly).

Is there an easy way I can force all my custom xaml canvases/paths to start at the top left corner without having to change all the co-ordinates as they can be quite complicated & confusing...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Canvas     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
            Name="svg2" 
            Width="744.09448819" 
            Height="1052.3622047">
    <Canvas.Resources/>
    <Canvas Name="layer1">
        <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
                Name="path2527" 
                Fill="#000000" 
                Data="M 124.57143 280.5848 
                        C 11.688854 257.94335 13.010144 92.855956 126.2267 73.767996 
                        C 136.54132 72.028986 139.57845 55.076466 129.57538 55.076466 
                        C 124.50146 55.076466 124.50146 55.076466 124.78645 44.826466 
                        C 125.07143 34.576466 125.07143 34.576466 143.82143 34.304396 
                        C 162.57143 34.032336 162.57143 34.032336 162.57143 44.554406 
                        C 162.57143 55.076466 162.57143 55.076466 158.07143 55.076466 
                        C 149.91303 55.076466 151.22222 72.552346 159.45035 73.483256 
                        C 172.00506 74.903666 188.51464 81.047016 199.44208 88.364526 
                        C 206.81274 93.300246 206.81274 93.300246 217.19163 82.956666 
                        C 227.57053 72.613096 227.57053 72.613096 237.57098 82.576016 
                        C 249.65906 94.618746 249.65278 92.540446 237.63732 104.51083 
                        C 227.70321 114.40766 227.70321 114.40766 230.73475 118.81385 
                        C 282.21093 193.63191 213.44867 298.41137 124.57143 280.5848 z 
                        M 165.13275 259.10241 C 211.76596 247.42014 241.46874 194.32531 225.28586 151.57647 
                        C 197.66068 78.601586 100.64894 72.395856 67.053854 141.45456 
                        C 36.048994 205.18873 95.530924 276.53864 165.13275 259.10241 z"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Canvas>
```

**EDIT**

XAML from my Application

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       Background="Black">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <!-- Text Content -->
        <Viewbox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Stretch="Fill">
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="" Foreground="{Binding Path=ForegroundColour, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontWeight="UltraBlack">
                <TextBlock.BitmapEffect>
                    <OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowColor="LightGray" GlowSize="1"/>
                </TextBlock.BitmapEffect>
            </TextBlock>
        </Viewbox>
        <!-- Clock Button -->
        <StackPanel x:Name="clockCanvas" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
            <Canvas>
                <Path Fill="White" Data="M 80.585224 169.88705 C 56.848634 164.45281 37.130464 149.09974 26.612084 127.86218 C 20.776944 116.08051 19.042194 109.26026 18.411614 95.621693 C 17.742034 81.139423 20.281694 69.295703 26.900484 56.033923 C 30.763404 48.293953 33.052344 45.284343 41.563214 36.754743 C 50.357724 27.940853 52.863904 26.058063 61.145654 22.043263 C 73.472574 16.067443 80.302404 14.275203 93.142854 13.646783 C 132.17775 11.736373 165.41602 36.874653 174.2177 74.964123 C 176.01638 82.747923 176.30366 86.330733 175.87409 95.621693 C 175.2441 109.24748 173.51166 116.06778 167.6846 127.86218 C 160.22115 142.96872 147.81411 155.37079 132.64285 162.88988 C 127.69285 165.34317 120.94285 168.08165 117.64285 168.97539 C 109.48593 171.18453 88.506924 171.70064 80.585224 169.88705 z M 114.33298 158.38025 C 138.19458 152.1303 157.00356 133.27793 163.19039 109.4101 C 166.24789 97.614743 165.60682 81.400023 161.63261 70.008973 C 154.86102 50.599923 138.9022 34.730683 118.97777 27.593553 C 112.42367 25.245813 110.15251 24.960583 97.642854 24.914143 C 85.595274 24.869433 82.666644 25.185343 76.642854 27.179453 C 56.153434 33.962263 38.951554 51.025423 32.100934 71.362183 C 28.991204 80.593743 28.279904 97.872723 30.607314 107.64549 C 36.460274 132.22201 55.481524 151.84134 79.816004 158.40146 C 89.349244 160.97144 104.47558 160.96214 114.33298 158.38025 z M 74.257654 127.73004 C 73.060584 126.89157 72.142854 125.16053 72.142854 123.74105 C 72.142854 122.3618 76.475084 113.43931 81.770024 103.9133 L 91.397194 86.593283 L 116.42452 73.227733 C 130.18955 65.876683 142.25911 59.721423 143.24577 59.549393 C 148.78735 58.583143 151.36312 65.507203 146.77616 69.039603 C 145.47447 70.042023 134.28893 76.221633 121.91939 82.772073 L 99.429314 94.681963 L 90.655084 110.50835 C 85.829254 119.21286 81.377304 126.72105 80.761854 127.19322 C 78.425624 128.98557 76.300574 129.16095 74.257654 127.73004 z"/>
            </Canvas>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Clock.Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="{Binding Path=ClockColor, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
        <!-- Stopwatch Button -->
        <StackPanel x:Name="stopwatchCanvas" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
            <Canvas>
                <Path Fill="White" Data="M 456.57143 413.78623 C 424.76159 407.88318 401.40597 387.81419 391.66856 358.01656 C 384.49111 336.05271 385.90264 312.2971 395.58282 292.14081 C 406.57688 269.24875 424.36364 255.18414 450.55979 248.66861 C 459.23591 246.51068 462.57143 243.62752 462.57143 238.28601 C 462.57143 234.57209 461.26377 233.0759 457.57143 232.56515 C 455.22815 232.24101 455.05312 231.80606 454.77933 225.62672 C 454.37878 216.58659 454.93673 216.21933 469.07143 216.21933 C 483.20612 216.21933 483.76408 216.58659 483.36353 225.62672 C 483.08974 231.80606 482.91471 232.24101 480.57143 232.56515 C 476.87909 233.0759 475.57143 234.57209 475.57143 238.28601 C 475.57143 243.64517 478.90235 246.50952 487.67076 248.69052 C 502.09593 252.27856 512.33883 257.28334 522.40939 265.66414 L 528.25588 270.52964 L 535.04617 266.59033 C 538.78083 264.42372 541.98531 262.79988 542.16724 262.9818 C 542.34916 263.16373 542.9491 270.82985 543.50044 280.01764 C 544.05177 289.20542 544.92955 297.51996 545.45104 298.49439 C 549.41462 305.9004 551.92828 326.46599 550.47372 339.58755 C 545.74863 382.21245 513.72136 412.69968 472.07143 414.21983 C 466.02143 414.44064 459.04643 414.24553 456.57143 413.78623 z M 484.11133 396.19916 C 509.12004 389.82047 527.09509 372.4139 534.18028 347.71372 C 536.52938 339.52434 536.76107 337.34058 536.28612 327.86563 C 535.41996 310.58629 536.13953 311.65678 516.46559 298.37892 L 499.40597 286.86545 L 506.06393 283.04239 L 512.7219 279.21933 L 509.39667 276.41622 C 504.79657 272.53843 493.35075 267.07396 485.57143 265.04156 C 476.97393 262.79541 461.16894 262.79541 452.57143 265.04156 C 416.00978 274.59352 393.80739 312.70351 404.104 348.23497 C 412.69338 377.87512 438.26527 397.46778 468.61133 397.65916 C 474.07293 397.69361 480.69917 397.06946 484.11133 396.19916 z"/>
            </Canvas>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Stopwatch.Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="{Binding Path=StopwatchColor, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
        <!-- Countdown Button -->
        <StackPanel x:Name="countdownCanvas" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">
            <Canvas>
                <Path Fill="White" Data="M 287 376.64338 C 261.09905 371.83686 240.66626 357.53966 228.20794 335.50549 C 220.52484 321.91692 216.26208 300.74934 217.94551 284.54537 C 218.83809 275.95377 221.36371 264.63392 223.12038 261.35154 C 223.64188 260.37711 224.51966 252.06257 225.07099 242.87479 C 225.62232 233.687 226.22227 226.02088 226.40419 225.83895 C 226.58612 225.65703 229.7906 227.28087 233.52525 229.44748 L 240.31554 233.38679 L 246.16204 228.52129 C 256.23259 220.14049 266.47549 215.13571 280.90066 211.54767 C 289.66907 209.36667 293 206.50232 293 201.14316 C 293 197.42924 291.69234 195.93305 288 195.4223 C 285.65671 195.09816 285.48168 194.66321 285.20789 188.48387 C 284.80735 179.44374 285.3653 179.07648 299.5 179.07648 C 313.63469 179.07648 314.19264 179.44374 313.7921 188.48387 C 313.51831 194.66321 313.34328 195.09816 311 195.4223 C 307.30766 195.93305 306 197.42924 306 201.14316 C 306 206.48467 309.33552 209.36783 318.01164 211.52576 C 344.20779 218.04129 361.99455 232.1059 372.98861 254.99796 C 379.97773 269.55087 382.72366 286.01418 380.90229 302.4447 C 376.1772 345.0696 344.14993 375.55683 302.5 377.07698 C 296.45 377.29779 289.475 377.10268 287 376.64338 z M 314.5399 359.05631 C 339.3313 352.73304 357.44235 335.33418 364.46743 311.09212 C 374.76404 275.56066 352.56165 237.45067 316 227.89871 C 307.40249 225.65256 291.5975 225.65256 283 227.89871 C 275.22067 229.93111 263.77485 235.39558 259.17476 239.27337 L 255.84952 242.07648 L 262.50749 245.89954 L 269.16546 249.7226 L 252.10584 261.23607 C 232.4319 274.51393 233.15146 273.44344 232.28531 290.72278 C 231.81036 300.19773 232.04205 302.38149 234.39115 310.57087 C 243.02502 340.67005 268.46417 360.32348 299.0399 360.51631 C 304.5015 360.55076 311.12774 359.92661 314.5399 359.05631 z"/>
            </Canvas>
            <Label  Content="{Binding Path=Countdown.Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="{Binding Path=CountdownColor, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Canvas x:Name="helpCanvas" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="Black" Visibility="Collapsed">
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Change the Text property of the TextBox within the ViewBox to see what it looks like with content.

Comment: Have you tried applying a TranslateTransform? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.translatetransform.aspx

Comment: I haven't, I've manually set Canvas.Top & Canvas.Left at the moment, which I suppose is similar(ish). But a translate transform's probably a better approach. Post this as an answer so I can upvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a TranslateTransform using the upper left point to move the content to the upper left corner of the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove Width and Height from the canvas that seems to shift the content. (Would that be enough or does that entail other problems?)

You can also drop all the wrapping canvases as the Path can be on its own here.

Comment: HB, I did actually remove all the wrapping canvases when sticking it into my project, this is just the raw XAML produced. I'll check the width/height thing although that will cause me problems because my Grid won't then be able to auto-size it column.

Comment: Yes, i would just drop the canvases to prevent those layout issues.

Comment: H.B, I've tried doing that and it didn't seem to really work. I've modified the XAML from my application slightly to make it work directly in XAMLPad etc, and posted it in my edit. As you can see the 3 graphical items don't appear on the left (should be all in a vertical line). Things seem to go a bit crazy if you put some data in (change the Text Property of the TextBox in the viewport to "00:00"). Any thoughts?

Comment: There the coordinates of the path are quite shifted, you'd need to add a vector to all points to move the path or you clip it respectively, not ideal either way i suppose.